# how do I replace no username with a string of choice in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I would like to have 'No user assigned' when there is no user to the ticket.

I did this to my model but I don't see any changes

```
def __unicode__(self):
        print 'gets here****'
        if not self.assigned:
            return 'No user assigned'
        else:
            return self.assigned
```

where assigned is the user assigned for a ticket.

IS ther any other way to do this?

I have my template and view like this:

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ ticket.title }}</td>
                    <td>
                    {% for user in ticket.assigned.all %}
                        {{ user.email }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </td>
```

and my View:

```
def get_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(View, self).get_data(**kwargs)
        project = self.project_described()

        context.update({
            "project": project,
            "tickets": project.tickets.all()
        })
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`for...empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)

It doesn't make much sense to include it in a model so you can just provide a default if the thing being iterated over in the for loop is empty

```
{% for user in ticket.assigned.all %}
     {{ user.email }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
{% empty %}
  No user assigned 
{% endfor %}
```

The advantage here is you could always use the `empty` section to insert a button into your table to allow people to be assigned (for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try use `{{ user }}` instead `{{ user.email }}`

Comment: For whoever is reviewing, technically this answer might actually solve the problem since it will invoke the correct method